# Django relation lookup not creating expected query

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using Django 1.11.6, python 3.4.2, postgresql, PyCharm 4.5.2, and windows 10 (only for development purposes).

**The goal is to utilize the 'Lookups that span relationships'**  from the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
# models
class AlphaType(models.Model):
    page_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, null=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class AlphaBoard(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    alpha_text = models.TextField(max_length=30000)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    fk_page_type = models.ForeignKey(AlphaType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='general')

#views
....
    q = AlphaBoard.objects.filter(fk_page_type__page_type='general')
    print(q.query)
....
```

Just fyi, the tables have the app name prepended to the model name and the foreign key has 'id' appended to the foreign key column name.

Result of the query print.

```
SELECT 
    "alpha_alphaboard"."id", "alpha_alphaboard"."title", 
    "alpha_alphaboard"."alpha_text", "alpha_alphaboard"."created_on", 
    "alpha_alphaboard"."modified_on", "alpha_alphaboard"."fk_page_type_id" 
FROM 
    "alpha_alphaboard" 
WHERE 
    "alpha_alphaboard"."fk_page_type_id" = "general"
```

What I was expecting.

```
SELECT 
    "alpha_alphaboard"."id", "alpha_alphaboard"."title", 
    "alpha_alphaboard"."alpha_text", "alpha_alphaboard"."created_on", 
    "alpha_alphaboard"."modified_on", "alpha_alphaboard"."fk_page_type_id" 
FROM 
    "alpha_alphaboard" 
INNER JOIN "alpha_alphaboard" ON "alpha_alphatype"
    "alpha_alphaboard"."fk_page_type_id" = "alpha_alphatype"."page_type"
WHERE
    "alpha_alphatype"."page_type" = "general"
```

Questions

1. Why is the query ignoring the page_type relation from the filter? Look at the result of the printed query and the filter within the views. I should also add that I had a related_name="fk_page_type" within the AlphaBoard.fk_page_type, but I removed it. So a follow up question is why is it still picking up the related_name?
2. How do you use the "relationship" from the docs to get the expected?
3. Is there a way to specify the join type?

Comment: you are just doing a forward lookup - which is not evaluating to a "reverse" relationship. your query is unnecessarily complicated to achieve the same result.. I would encourage you to go by the resulting queryset, rather than the query it generates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `page_type` is the primary key of the `AlphaType` model and its value is just written in the `fk_page_type` column of the `AlphaBoard` table, no join is needed:

```
q = AlphaBoard.objects.filter(fk_page_type__page_type='general')
```

is the same as

```
q = AlphaBoard.objects.filter(fk_page_type_id='general')
```

the field of the related model you are using in your filter is the exact foreign key value that is written in the primary table.

As for the `related_name`, it is used to access the **reverse** relation:

```
class AlphaBoard(models.Model):
    fk_page_type = models.ForeignKey(AlphaType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='boards')

t = AlphaType(...)
boards = t.boards.all()  # gives all boards with type t
boards = t.alphaboard_set.all()  # default: lowermodelname_set
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I was not aware of the forward and reverse relation lookup.